# If user exist in db - display all form fields, if not - display them as a read only

Tags: php, html, forms

I have simple HTML form with two buttons (search and update).
This code below will retrieve values from MySQL via "Search" button, and after that retrieved value "age" will be inserted into DB via button "Update".

HTML form has fields:

- Privateno (Search Key)
- User
- Age

**So, what I really need as a help...**

How to manage that in HTML form only Search Key (privateno) field be editable, and all others to be "read-only" until and unless if "privateno" really exist in the database (in that case, fields value will be auto-inserted from the DB)?

```
<?php

// php code to search data in mysql database and set it in input text

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    // id to search
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    // connect to mysql
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

    // mysql search query
    $query = "SELECT `user`, `age`, `privateno` FROM `test` WHERE `privateno` = $id LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    // if id exist 
    // show data in inputs
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $user = $row['user'];
            $age = $row['age'];
            $privateno = $row['privateno'];
        }  
    }

    // if the id not exist
    // show a message and clear inputs
    else
    {
        echo "User doesn't exist";
        $user = "";
        $age = "";
        $privateno = "";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

// in the first time inputs are empty
else
{
    $user = "";
    $age = "";
    $privateno = "";
}

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    $age = $_POST['lname'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (text)
            VALUES ('$age')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            PrivateNo:<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $privateno;?>"><br><br>
            First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $user;?>"><br>
            <br>
            Age:<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $age;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="search" name="search" />
            <input type="submit" value="update" name="update" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $user;?>"readonly><br>
```

Simple as that, my bad, I got an idea just few minutes after posting here.

I thought that if I put field in "read only" mode, that wouldn't retrieve DB values to that specific "readonly" field.

Comment: I hope you do realise that's a very insecure solution. Your entire script is insecure and wide open to SQL injection not to mention.

Comment: What part exactly, what do you recommend?

Comment: I have auth.php file also, if that change something? "<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>"

Comment: I'd recommend using [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and validating user input with Regex for example